# Turning Object containing Array with Object of Observables into Observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Let's say I have this object:

```
const myObject = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    obs: [{ c: 'foobar', d: of(true) }, { c: 'foobar', d: of(true) }]
}
```

How can I return `myObject` like as a `Observable<MyObject>` in a similar fashion `forkJoin()` does this for a simple array of resolved Observables.

The goal would be to:

```
myObject.subscribe((ob) => console.log(ob));
```

and receive:

```
{
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    obs: [{ c: 'foobar', d: true }, { c: 'foobar', d: true }]
}
```

In other words I want to subscribe only once to `myObject` and not to every Observable inside of `myObject` individually.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What is `of(true)` inside your `myObject`?

Comment: @navnath wraps the boolean values into Observables for example purposes.

Comment: So you have `obs` array, inside which you have objects with second as Observable `d:of(true)`? So you want to resolve observable inside array and return one final observable of myObject?

Comment: @navnath correct!

Comment: is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kngyoe) you want?

Comment: @navnath This is exactly what I needed! I did not think it would be this complicated but thank you very much! Do you maybe have any idea how to simplify this further? If not then maybe I need to overthink the structure of `myObject`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, `forkJoin` is basically all you need. You can use map to create your updated object afterward.

That might look like this:

```ts
const myObject = {
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
  obs: [{ c: 'foobar', d: of(true) }, { c: 'foobar', d: of(true) }]
}

forkJoin(
  myObject.obs.map(oby => oby.d)
).pipe(
  map(obsRes => ({
    ...myObject,
    obs: myObject.obs.map((oby, i) => ({
      ...oby, 
      d: obsRes[i]
    }))
  }))
).subscribe(console.log);
```